# In Java, A.super.func(), what's the meaning of it?(Interface default)

Tags: java

```
interface A{
     default void func(){
         System.out.println("This function is a default function in interface A!");
     }
}
interface B{
     default void func(){
         System.out.println("This function is a default function in interface B");
     }
}
class C implements A,B{
     public void func(){
         System.out.println("func in class C!");
         A.super.func();//What's meaning?
     }
}
```

Comment: `super` is needed because you can't use `A.func()` since it's not static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both `A` And `B` have a default implementation of `func()`, `A.super.func()` allows you to invoke `A`'s default implementation of `func()` (and similarly `B.super.func()` would invoke `B`'s default implementation of `func()`).

Comment: why use interface.super?

Comment: @ShawnLiu If you want to invoke the default implementation of a specific interface, and there are multiple interfaces that implement that method, that's the only way to specify which implementation you want.

Comment: @Eran super is needed because you can't use A.func() since it's not static

Comment: @YassinHajaj that's true. I assumed the question was more about the interface name than the super keyword itself (i.e. why `A.super.func()` instead of simply `super.func()`)

Answer (score 4):

from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

> If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword super

thus by calling `super.func()` you can access the `func()` method of your superclass. But here both `A & B` has the function with same name, thus you have to tell the compiler which super is to be used.

So by telling `A.super` you are informing compiler to use the method of interface A. same goes for B

Comment: super is needed because you can't use A.func() since it's not static

Comment: yah .. that is obvious :)

Comment: yes but not to OP I think. Hence his comment on Eran's answer.